# Не отрабатывает fsockopen

Tags: php, сокет

Есть скрипт, который с помощью fsockopen связывается с АТС. На одном хостинге скрипт работал, там стояла php 5.3, потом перенес на второй хостинг, и там стоит 5.4, и не работает, ничего не происходит. Ошибок и предупреждений нет. В чем может быть проблема? Может, на хостинге необходимо что-то настроить? Данная строчка работала на первом хостинге, но на втором выдавало ошибку из-за &, поэтому на втором хостинге убрал.

```
$sconn = fsockopen ($strhost, $strport, &$errno, &$errstr, $timeout) or die("Connection to $strhost:$strport failed");
```

Comment: @TF03, начиная с PHP5.4 интерпретатор сам знает, что этот параметр передается по ссылке (что амперсанд туда нужно "подставить"), поэтому в этом нет необходимости.

Comment: @Etki, это я сделал, но все равно какая-то фигня, и ничего не понятно

Comment: @TF03 могу в этом случае разве что посоветовать доки по [передаче параметров по ссылке](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.php).

Comment: на втором хостинге нужный порт для передачи открыт?..